# Why does ggtheme not print in ggsurvplot / R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

**Solved: packeges needed to be updated**

Please find `My Data` below.

I have produced a combined Kaplan-Meier plot of progression-free and overall survival.

I have used the following script

```
pfs <- survfit(Surv(resp.time, response) ~ 1, conf.type="log", data=w)
os <- survfit(Surv(Follow.up.death, Death) ~ 1, conf.type="log", data=w)

fit <- list(PFS = pfs, OS = os)
ggsurvplot(fit, data = w, combine = TRUE, 
           risk.table = TRUE,                  
           conf.int = TRUE,                    
           conf.int.style = "ribbon",            
           censor = TRUE,                     
           tables.theme = theme,
           ggtheme = theme,
           xlim = c(0,36),
           ylim = c(0.25,1),
           alpha=0.8,
           size=0.7,
           conf.int.alpha=c(0.1),
           break.x.by = 6,
           palette = c("#1C73C2","red"))
```

Which gave

[image]

As you can see, I have designed my own "theme" given by:

```
theme <- theme(axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
               panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "gray98"),
               panel.grid.minor = element_line(colour = "gray98"),
               panel.border = element_blank(),
               panel.background = element_blank())
```

It seems that when I print the plot, `theme` is only added to table and not the plot itself although `ggtheme=theme`.

Can I add the `theme` somehow to the plot as in the table?

A sample of `My Data`

```
w <- structure(list(WHO = c(1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L
), Death = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Follow.up.death = c(18, 
2, 14, 17, 31, 4, 20, 15, 12, 19, 10, 17, 27, 22, 3, 43, 24, 
14, 13, 5, 12, 137, 22, 87, 48, 24, 72, 32, 14, 83, 68, 56, 57, 
18, 16, 70, 1.9, 69.2, 126.3, 41.6, 17.9, 1.3, 87.4, 4.4, 137.4, 
17.5, 95.8, 65.2, 14.8, 98.5, 16.6, 74.9, 10.3, 43.4, 32.5, 4.8, 
7.3, 107.8, 6.8, 18.3, 33, 25.2, 49.2, 15.9, 1.2, 42.7, 1, 9, 
1.8, 15.6, 8.9, 15, 16.4, 7.7, 75.5, 12.2, 54.8, 22.2, 9.7, 14.3, 
5.2, 64.5, 21.8, 0.2, 7.3, 18.7, 5.1, 17.3, 27.4, 16, 24.2, 9.7, 
8.2, 5.7, 41.8, 10.6, 22.8, 4.8, 6, 4, 50, 21, 30, 5, 11, 12), 
    response = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), resp.time = c(18, 2, 13, 17, 22, 2, 
    6, 5, 12, 8, 3, 2, 1, 21, 2, 43, 4, 2, 4, 5, 0.1, 137, 4, 
    87, 17, 24, 72, 19, 14, 83, 68, 56, 57, 18, 14, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, 15.6, 8.9, 15, 16.4, 7.7, 75.5, 3, 54.8, 22.2, 12, 14.3, 
    6, 12, 21.8, 6, 3, 12, 3, 6, 3, 3, 12, 9.7, 3, 3, 12, 3, 
    6, 3, 6, 4, 50, 21, 30, 5, 11, 12)), .Names = c("WHO", "Death", 
"Follow.up.death", "response", "resp.time"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-106L))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the major and minor gridlines are there, it's just incredibly faint and/or the something in the export settings means the exported image isn't detailed enough to display them.

With your code, modifying some of the parameters:

```
theme <- theme(axis.line = element_line(colour = "green"),
               panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "red"),
               panel.grid.minor = element_line(colour = "blue"),
               panel.border = element_blank(),
               panel.background = element_blank())
```

[image]

With:

```
theme <- theme(axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
               panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "gray98"),
               panel.grid.minor = element_line(colour = "gray98"),
               panel.border = element_blank(),
               panel.background = element_rect(fill = "#BFD5E3", colour = "#6D9EC1"))
```

[image]

Comment: Please see my answer below @VictorNautica. You mentioned something about export settings? Any suggestions to what I might need to change?

Answer (score 0):

That is really weird.

This is what I get

```
theme <- theme(axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
               panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "red"),
               panel.grid.minor = element_line(colour = "red"),
               panel.border = element_blank(),
               panel.background = element_blank())
```

[image]

But I do get the following: Warning messages:

```
1: Removed 1 rows containing missing values (geom_path). 
2: Removed 1 rows containing missing values (geom_path).
```

Comment: That's strange. If you assign the ggsurvplot object to `my_plot` with the above code, and run `my_plot[["plot"]][["theme"]][["panel.grid.major"]][["colour"]]`, what gets returned?

Comment: It returns `NULL`. Did you see I just added that the plot returns the following each time: 1: `Removed 1 rows containing missing values (geom_path). 2: Removed 1 rows containing missing values (geom_path).`

Comment: Yes that's related to some of the data from the df not being mapped, it shouldn't matter for the theme. I'm not too experienced with modifying ggplot internals so I don't know what else to suggest, but if that's returning `NULL` then somehow the theme isn't being applied to the plot object, only the table. I only hypothesized something about the export settings could be impacting it as I could hardly see the `grey98` lines myself in the OP.

Does it happen in other instances of RStudio on your computer? If it does the only other thing I can suggest is to try updating the packages involved.

Comment: So updating the packeges solved the problem.Thank you.